# Использование апострофа

Tags: орфография, апостроф

Допустимо ли в современной русской письменности использовать апостроф? Есть ли на сей счёт правила?

Answer (score 2):

Не "допустимо", а необходимо в соответствующих случаях.

Во-первых, при передаче иностранных имён собственных — там, где он есть в языке-оригинале и при склонении написанных латиницей имён или терминов: д'Артаньян, behemothus'а.

Во-вторых для передачи особенностей речи:   "Умигать — не в помигушки иг'ать, - вдруг картавя,  сказал  неизвестно откуда-то появившийся перед спящим Алексеем Турбиным полковник Най-Турс" (Булгаков).

Наконец, как специальных знак при транскрибировании и т.п., эти случаи, впрочем, не относятся к письменности как таковой.

Что же касается использования апострофа вместо твердого знака (подозреваю, что именно это вы и хотели спросить), то в современной орфографии оно не применяется.